# Использование JSON в c# (System.Runtime.Serialization)

Tags: c#, json

Задача хранить сериализованные данные в JSON. Нашел даже пример: [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.5.php)

Но есть проблема: данные JSON в файле сохраняются в одну строчку:

> [{"Age":29,"Company":{"Name":"Microsoft"},"Name":"Tom"},{"Age":25,"Company":{"Name":"Apple"},"Name":"Bill"}]

Как сериализовывать в JSON, что бы данные имели нормальное форматирование, как и в примере в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661063/how-do-i-get-formatted-json-in-net-using-c) советуют использовать либу JSON.NET

Пример с либой:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonPrettyPrint
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product product = new Product
                {
                    Name = "Apple",
                    Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28),
                    Price = 3.99M,
                    Sizes = new[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" }
                };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(json);

            Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
        }
    }

    internal class Product
    {
        public String[] Sizes { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
{
  "Sizes": [
    "Small",
    "Medium",
    "Large"
  ],
  "Price": 3.99,
  "Expiry": "\/Date(1230447600000-0700)\/",
  "Name": "Apple"
}
```

Как я понимаю `Formatting.Indented` задает отступы.

P.S Если верить [табличке](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm), то **JSON.NET** круче реализации от майков.

Comment: Да, Json.NET — любимая разработчиками библиотека, рекомендуется всеми и везде.

Comment: Наверное, имеет смысл упомянуть, как подключать (например, через nuget).

Comment: К сожалению пример выше не работает http://i12.pixs.ru/storage/0/4/6/2017010819_3152033_24697046.png

Comment: @polsok, ты похоже не ту либу поставил. Вот это поставь PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json . А сейчас у тебя стоит Схема.

Comment: теперь все работает, премного благодарен